# Is the set $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:\left\|(x,y,z)\right\|\le 2\}$ a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was hoping someone could verify my work. Is the set

$$U=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:  \|(x,y,z)\|\le2\}$$

a subspace? Using the standard inner product.

**My work:**

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$$u = (0,0,2) \:\:{\rm and}\:\: v = (0,2,0)$$

Then

$$\|u\|=\sqrt{0+0+4} = 2\:\:{\rm and}\:\: \|v\|=\sqrt{0+4+0} = 2$$

But

$$\|u+v\| = \sqrt{0+4+4} = \sqrt{8} \not\le 2$$

Thus, it is not a subspace. Does that look correct?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the lines going through the origin, planes going through the origin, $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself and the origin $\{(0,0,0\}$.

Comment: The vector $(1,0,0)$ belongs to $U$; does $(100,0,0)=100(1,0,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine, it is not closed under addition, hence it is not a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. You showed that the set is not closed under addition, and therefore it can't be a vector space. You can argue that this set represents a ball of radius $2$, so you can visualize why you argument is true.